# If same name is in table multiple times and a certain column has 2 different kinds of data don't select any of those rows with that name

Tags: mysql

I have this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT visitors_table.name, visitors_table.visitor_submitted 
FROM visitors_table 
LEFT JOIN list_data 
ON visitors_table.vid = list_data.id 
WHERE visitors_table.cid='2050' AND list_data.seed != '1'
```

And result is this

```
aaron 0000-00-00 00:00:00
brandon 2016-05-24 09:48:27
will 0000-00-00 00:00:00
amy 0000-00-00 00:00:00
amy 2016-05-24 17:14:27
amy 2016-05-24 17:20:00
```

I want to select all the ones where date equals 0000-00-00 00:00:00, but if that person has another record where the date is not all zeros then i don't want to select that person.

So i can do this

```
SELECT DISTINCT visitors_table.name, visitors_table.visitor_submitted 
FROM visitors_table 
LEFT JOIN list_data 
ON visitors_table.vid = list_data.id 
WHERE visitors_table.cid='2050' AND list_data.seed != '1' AND visitors_table.visitor_submitted='0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

But that gives this result

```
aaron 0000-00-00 00:00:00
will 0000-00-00 00:00:00
amy 0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

That's not the result i want.  i want this result, because amy has multiple entries with and without dates of zeros.

```
aaron 0000-00-00 00:00:00
will 0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

How would you go about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get all the ones where date equals `0000-00-00 00:00:00` then filter out the ones that have date other than `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

```
SELECT DISTINCT visitors_table.name, visitors_table.visitor_submitted   
FROM visitors_table 
LEFT JOIN list_data 
ON visitors_table.vid = list_data.id 
WHERE visitors_table.cid='2050' AND list_data.seed != '1' AND visitors_table.visitor_submitted = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
and visitors_table.name not in 
(SELECT DISTINCT visitors_table.name 
FROM visitors_table 
LEFT JOIN list_data 
ON visitors_table.vid = list_data.id 
WHERE visitors_table.cid='2050' AND list_data.seed != '1' AND visitors_table.visitor_submitted <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
```

You can do the same in a different way with join, etc. if you dont have appropriate indexes and the query is too slow for you

Comment: Thanks, and by the way the DISTINCT wasn't supposed to be there. it didn't work in this case anyway or else i wouldn't have gotten amy 3 times in the original query. so this solution works with and without DISTINCT.

Comment: Actually, with the solution, DISTINCT is needed in the first select, but not needed in second select.

Comment: Agree to that. I put a distinct in the second select to reduce the sample size for the `not in` search. Depends on how big is your dataset and which way would give you a better query time

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated NOT EXISTS condition.

```
SELECT DISTINCT v.name, v.visitor_submitted 
FROM visitors_table v
LEFT JOIN list_data 
   ON v.vid = list_data.id 
WHERE v.cid='2050' 
  AND list_data.seed != '1'
  AND NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM visitors_table v2
      WHERE v2.name = v.name
        AND v2.visitor_submitted <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
  )
```

Please note that MySQL will convert your LEFT JOIN to an INNER JOIN because of this condition: `list_data.seed != '1'`. If you nead a LEFT JOIN, you should move that condition into the ON clause.